# How to submit a form and save to the database when some form fields are empty

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want some of my field leave it blank, for some proposes but form don't submit to the database if some input is blank.

form work fine if I have all values in the form fields but if there are one or two values blank all information not submit to the database.

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     //process the form


     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $address = $_POST["address"];
     $contact = $_POST["contact"];
     $transaction = $_POST["transaction"];
     $status = $_POST["status"];
     $flemingia = $_POST["flemingia"];
     $indigofera = $_POST["indigofera"];
     $ipil_ipil = $_POST["ipil_ipil"];
     $acid_ipil_ipil = $_POST["acid_ipil_ipil"];
     $red_calliandra = $_POST["red_calliandra"];
     $white_calliandra = $_POST["white_calliandra"];
     $centrosema = $_POST["centrosema"];
     $goat_manual = $_POST["goat_manual"];
     $lbc_tracking = $_POST["lbc_tracking"];
     $debit_amount = $_POST["debit_amount"];
     $credit_amount = $_POST["credit_amount"];



     $query  = "INSERT INTO orders (";
     $query .= "name, address, contact, transaction, flemingia, indigofera, ipil_ipil, acid_ipil_ipil, ";
     $query .= "red_calliandra, white_calliandra, centrosema, goat_manual, lbc_tracking, debit_amount, credit_amount, status";
     $query .= ") VALUES (";
     $query .= "'{$name}', '{$address}', {$contact}, '{$transaction}', {$flemingia}, {$indigofera}, {$ipil_ipil}, {$acid_ipil_ipil}, ";
     $query .= "{$red_calliandra}, {$white_calliandra}, {$centrosema}, {$goat_manual}, {$lbc_tracking}, {$debit_amount}, {$credit_amount}, {$status}";
     $query .= ")";
     $order_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

     if($order_set){
       redirect_to("orders.php");
     } else{
       $message = "order creation failed";
     }

     } else {


     }
```

Comment: then you better make sure you to insert them with some value other than null

Comment: i try to change the item that i want to leave it blank from `NOT NULL` TO `NULL` and it seems not working

Comment: Have you tried Ryan's answer below? @jhunlio Also check if you have an AUTO_INCREMENT or primary key on one of your columns in your query. You may also have a foreign key.

Comment: yes i try ryan's answer but also not work yes my id is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and no `foreign key`

Answer (score 0):

For each of your `$_POST` vars,

`$name = (isset( $_POST['name'] )) ? $_POST['name'] : '';`

This will set $name to an empty string if it doesn't exist.